# Fuel vs. Propellant

Tags: terminology, rocket-science

I am looking at http://nathangeffen.webfactional.com/spacetravel/spacetravel.php.

My understanding that his fuel requirements are based on the energy needed to move the spacecraft + fuel the distance entered at a constant acceleration entered (and takes into account the diminishing mass of the spaceship as fuel is expended).  So far so good.

What I am unclear about is that the only thing mentioned is fuel... but not propellant.  Does this site assume that the fuel IS the propellant (or that propellant mass is included in the fuel?)

Comment: Yeah, ... what CountTO10 said,... but I'll add one more phrase:  _reaction mass_.   Reaction mass is what exits the rocket nozzle.  Fuel is what provides the energy.  When they say "propellant", they're usually talking about something that serves both purposes.

Comment: @CountTo10 -- What you wrote is incorrect. In a jet engine, fuel and propellant are synonymous. For example, MIL-STD JP-8 and NATO F-34 are the same thing. The "P" in JP-8 is short for propellant while the "F" in F-34 is short for fuel.

Comment: @DavidHammen Wikipedia, FWIW, agrees with you _A propellant or propellent is a chemical substance used in the production of energy or pressurized gas that is subsequently used to create movement of a fluid or to generate propulsion of a vehicle_ and so I would say the (working) fluid here is air, so I will delete my comment. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site makes a rather odd presumption, which is contained in the line "Fuel conversion efficiency". This assumes that fuel mass is converted to ship kinetic energy at a fixed rate, or $$ \Delta KE = \eta \Delta mc^2$$ where $\eta$ is the conversion efficiency. This is not the way things are usually expressed. Ordinarily, rocket fuel/engine systems are characterized by specific impulse, change in momentum per unit fuel mass consumed, and as velocity increases the effective thrust decreases. However, the page contains the hidden assumption that the "rocket" involved actually uses a photon drive, and this accounts for the discrepancy (since the speed of light is constant for all observers).

Otherwise, David Hammen's answer is excellent.

I would add, though, that non-chemical drives make a very clear distinction between fuel and propellant. In these systems, the fuel is typically radioactive materials, while the propellant is the reaction mass tossed out the back, which may well be some material such as caesium, indium or xenon. See [the Wiki page on ion thrusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster) for a starting point.

Comment: O.k.  That is the piece I was missing.  I was looking for the assumptions made by the website, and that was the big one.  So what I am taking out of this is:

Answer (score 1):

With regard to spacecraft, "propellant" is an all-encompassing term that describes all of the stuff that describes all of the stuff the spacecraft carries that will eventually be ejected to generate thrust.

In bi-propellant chemical engines used to launch spacecraft into space, the propellant comprises the fuel (the stuff that burns in the presence of an oxidizer) and the oxidizer. In monopropellant chemical engines such as hydrazine passing through a catalyst bed, the hydrazine is the propellant. In cold gas systems, the compressed gas is the propellant. In ion propulsion systems, the xenon (or whatever) that will eventually be ejected is the propellant. In a hypothetical matter/antimatter propulsion system, the matter and antimatter that will eventually be ejected as photons are the propellant.

Some people such as the referenced website use "fuel" as the all-encompassing term. Strictly speaking, that's incorrect. "Fuel" refers to the reducing agents used in a chemical rocket that are oxidized by an oxidizing agent. The fuel (reducer) and the oxidizer collectively form the propellant in a bi-prop chemical rocket.

That said, it's best to not be so pedantic, particularly when discussing the ideal rocket equation or its relativistic equivalent. "Fuel" in this context is a synonym for propellant.

Comment: O.k.  That is the piece I was missing.  I was looking for the assumptions made by the website, and that was the big one.  So what I am taking out of this is:
A)  Propellant basically all the mass that is used in propulsion, be it to be consumed to create energy or being chucked out that back.  Includes fuel, oxidizer, and any cold mass just added to the nix to increase thrust.  In the website menti0ned he uses the term fuel... but a more accurate term would be propellant.